# how to sniff from a remote machine?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, packet-sniffer

I have a PC and a tablet that connected to a TP-Link ADSL modem.

**PROBLEM:**
 I want to see the packets that send and receive from my modem **not my PC**( to see both wire and wireless packets)

I search very places for do this but I can't sniff from modem.

**NOTE**
 - I follow [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/530020) but I can't connect to my modem with **ssh**

Comment: In order to capture traffic from your modem, you need to capture traffic _on_ your modem. If you do not know how to do this, I would suggest you refer to your modem documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way, though it requires some extra hardware.

A quick Google search of "TP Link ADSL Modem" shows a device with antennas on its head, so I suspect it is **both** an ADSL modem and a wireless access point (and router).  Newer DSL and cable modem devices have wifi routers built in, which is usually nice but problematic in your case because what you really want to do is insert a packet sniffer ***between*** those two devices.

My suggestion to you, then - go out and pick up a separate wi-fi router (I've seen them as cheap as $10-$20, or you could borrow one).  Then, connect to your current DSL modem's administrator interface (most likely a web page at its address; check the documentation that came with it) and switch OFF its wireless functionality.  Then, connect your new wireless router to a packet sniffer, and that to your DSL modem, and have all your devices talk to the new wireless router.

I'm also assuming you have some sort of packet sniffing device handy.  If it were me, I'd throw together a Linux machine with two network interfaces and put it in between the wifi router and DSL modem, but there may be another route you're more comfortable with.

In any case, that then gets you what you want - the ability to see the traffic coming out of the modem towards both your PC and your tablet.